# Handling raw JavaScript being returned to .ajax error function despite 200 OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm making the following jQuery.ajax() call to a product I have no control over:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WfWsR",
    data: { method: 'getInfo',
        nodeID: nodeID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data, response, replyxhr){
        return data;
    },
    error: function(replyxhr, response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(replyxhr);
        return response;
    }
});
```

The POST succeeds with a 200 OK, but instead of going to the success function it ends up in error, with the response variable set to "error" and the replyxhr variable set to Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}.

Trying the POST manually through Postman yields the result:

```
new Array(
  new Array(
    new Array(
      "15", "1", ""
    )
  ), 
  new Array(
    new Array(
      "1", "3757", "3757", "user", "2013-01-22 15:09:04.354"
    )
  ), 
  new Array(
  ), 
  new Array(
    "3762", "ABCD", "test Purge Documents", "50", "purge Documents", "Administrator", "2013-01-22 15:07:57.065"
  ), "13d886ddf90"
)
```

That's a lot of JavaScript; technically I only need one item from any of those arrays. The reason I believe it's not working in jQuery is because that sort of return is probably invalid, especially given the dataType: "text". But I can't use dataType: "script" either; that uses an implicit GET instead of a POST, and the URL in question does not support GET.

Are there any other options I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own xhr call (sans error-handling) to allow this. Terrible solution to a terrible problem. (Double fail for the eval()).

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "method=getInfo&nodeID=" + nodeID;

xhReq.open("POST", "/WfWsR", true);
xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhReq.onreadystatechange = onPostSubmit;
xhReq.send(params);
var response = eval(xhReq.response);
var stepIDx = response[0][0][0];

return stepIDx;

function onPostSubmit() {
    if (xhReq.readyState==4 || xhReq.readyState=="complete") { 
        if (xhReq.status != 200) {
            alert('BadStatus');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess that you're telling Ajax to expect `text` but it is getting something else, according to the `content-type` of the response. It appears the server is giving you Javascript so I wouldn't be surprised if the content-type is `text/javascript`.

I've never had to deal with this but if this is your problem, the docs do say that there is a solution in jQuery 1.5 and higher:

> multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert
>   a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what
>   you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as
>   XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP
>   request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML:
>   "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml"
>   will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that,
>   convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

via http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (see the doc for dataType)

That means you can possibly use this: `dataType: "script text"` to have a Javascript response interpreted as text. Of course, you could also just use `dataType: "script"` to have it interpreted as script.